# Blender 2.8 objects invisible

Tags: modeling

I just added a collection and started to draw an object, and hid the other layers. But I cannot make the previous collection/layer to turn back on. The initial objects Only shows in render mode. in any other view mode, I cannot see the object. only the most recent layer shows up as shown in this image.  [image]

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be in Local view, where only selected objects are displayed.

[image]

Hit <kbd>/</kbd>, or go to *View > Local View > Toggle Local View* (in the viewport header) to return to Global.