# Why isn't my mesh appearing in the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

I've been working on a detailed character model for some time. I finished the retopology, hid the sculpt, and now I can't seem to reveal the sculpt again in either object or edit mode (selecting the object from the outliner and hitting tab).

[image: The sculpt listed as visible in the outliner]

[image: Object properties displaying the mesh as visible]

I took a look at my item menu and the sculpt's location and scale look right.

[image: The item menu]

However, when I append the sculpt object into an empty .blend file, it's completely visible.

[image: The character sculpt imported into an empty .blend file]

What's causing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably viewport visibility was disabled accidentally. Check *object properties>visibility*, is viewports selected?

Comment: I checked viewport visibility and it appears to be selectable and visible in viewports and renders;;

https://i.imgur.com/Yog1jnF.png

Comment: thanks for the info :) So that other users will see it, please [edit] your question and add the new information and image there. Thanks :)

Comment: hello, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I'm sorry, but because this is part of a bigger project I can't agree to this site's terms of service.

https://i.imgur.com/5iCsclc.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Objects Not Showing in Other Workspace Viewports, Only Default](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111995/objects-not-showing-in-other-workspace-viewports-only-default)  and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124644/blender-2-8-objects-invisible

Answer (score 0):

Check visibility toggle in the Outliner:

[image: Visibility toggle]

For the object itself and the collection, to which that object belongs to.

Also check these settings in object properties [image]

Comment: The object is visible in the outliner!

https://i.imgur.com/qpEJQm5.png

I've also checked the visibility in object properties, and it appears to be visible there as well.

https://i.imgur.com/Yog1jnF.png

Comment: well, try Alt+H in object mode, then get into edit mode, select all with "A" and press Alt+H again

Comment: Alright! I did so. However, I'm still unable to see the object in the viewport, and I can't seem to be able to select anything on the model at all. https://i.imgur.com/OyqJ9dq.png

What's really odd is that I'm able to "feel around" the model in sculpt mode... https://i.imgur.com/utBUVtn.png

Comment: Did you try "/" key? may be it got lost in local-view mode or something?

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to just press the "/" key! My mesh was just in local view.

Comment: Would suggest in some cases that deleting the question is more appropriate.

Comment: I'm sorry;; I just think it may be helpful to others in the future to keep this post up because I couldn't find a solution by simply searching the stack exchange, and that it took three users' engagement to resolve the issue.